# Using css child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply css on the first A element inside .Outer,

```
 .Outer > a:first-child {font-weight:bold}
```

doesn't work. Why?

```
<div class="Outer">
 <img src='image123.jpg' />
 <a href="Default.aspx?ID=4083" id="ctl00_CPH_Main_Rep_List2_ctl03_HyperLink1">John Johnsson</a>
 <a href="../Users/ViewList.aspx?module=Occupation&amp;ID=70">Doctor</a>
 <a href="../Workplaces/Default.aspx?ID=31">Mayo Clinica>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `<a>` isn't the first child, `<img/>` is. What you're looking for is `.Outer > a:first-of-type` or `.Outer > a:nth-child(2)`. Take not these "more advanced" selector don't work in all browsers *coughIEcough*

Comment: Oh hey, I either forgot about or didn't know those pseudo classes.

Comment: this is the best solution but it has poor browser support (non IE8, FF3) so I'll have to use other alternatives

Comment: can you maybe use a server-side script to add a class to the first link there?

Answer (score 0):

try it without the angle bracket. also, the `:first-child` pseudo class isn't recognized by all browsers.

it's also possible that your CSS is being overridden by an existing rule. use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) in firefox to see exactly what styles are being applied.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will only work if the *first child* of your div.Outer was an a element.  `:first-child` does exactly what it says, it only matches an element if that element is the first child of something.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to select only the first matching child element of an element using CSS only.

Comment: thx all, thought a:first-child would apply to the first A element only...

will check out alternatives!

Comment: I gave you an alternative, check my answer :/

Comment: @henasraf: definitely check out David's answer, it might be useful if you don't have to support some browsers.

Comment: Not sure if first-child in jQuery will fail, but you can do something else: `$('.Outer a').first().addClass('first');`

Answer (score 0):

Because the first child is the image, this would work:

```
<div class="Outer">
 <a href="Default.aspx?ID=4083" id="ctl00_CPH_Main_Rep_List2_ctl03_HyperLink1">John Johnsson</a>
 <a href="../Users/ViewList.aspx?module=Occupation&amp;ID=70">Doctor</a>
 <a href="../Workplaces/Default.aspx?ID=31">Mayo Clinic</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>***Disclaimer***: sorry I won't be testing this, just throwing some ideas.</sup>

Since image is actually the first element, here's an alternative simple idea, if you haven't figured any yet:

```
<div class="Outer">
 <img src='image123.jpg' />
</div>
<div class="Outer">
 <a href="Default.aspx?ID=4083" id="ctl00_CPH_Main_Rep_List2_ctl03_HyperLink1">John Johnsson</a>
 <a href="../Users/ViewList.aspx?module=Occupation&amp;ID=70">Doctor</a>
 <a href="../Workplaces/Default.aspx?ID=31">Mayo Clinica</a>
</div>
```

It shouldn't affect `img` since it's just bold.

---

Another approach would be modifying just the CSS and not touching the HTML:

```
.Outer a:first-child {font-weight:bold;}
```

That will affect every child from Outer, but I believe it would work in this case if there's nothing more inside Outer.

---

The best thing to do, whoever, would be one different `div` for each group of elements. In this case, it would be something like this:

**CSS**

```
.Outer {font-size:10pt;}
.Outer-Head {boder:0;}
.Outer-Body {font-weight:none;}
.Outer-First {font-weight:bold;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Outer">
 <div class="Outer-Head">
  <img src='image123.jpg' />
 </div>
 <div class="Outer-Body">
  <div class="Outer-First">
   <a href="Default.aspx?ID=4083" id="ctl00_CPH_Main_Rep_List2_ctl03_HyperLink1">John Johnsson</a>
  </div>
  <a href="../Users/ViewList.aspx?module=Occupation&amp;ID=70">Doctor</a>
  <a href="../Workplaces/Default.aspx?ID=31">Mayo Clinica</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

It will give you best results. Just take a look at StackOverflow source on how it's done. It's very smooth.